# Ruby-on-Rails accessing table id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-routes

I have an application that includes two tables - Companies and Company_Listings.  A Company may have one or more Company_Listings.  Currently the application sets the company.id in cache (e.g. Rails.cache.write("company", @company) ) and within the Company_Listings controller I access the Company.id via @company = Rails.cache.read("company").

I now realise I should not be doing this and should be accessing the Company.Id from the routes (at least that is my understanding). This I can't do.
The relevant code including the changes routes follows.

Company Model

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :company_listings, dependent: :destroy
```

CompanyListing Model

```
class CompanyListing < ActiveRecord::Base
   ...
   belongs_to :company
```

Routes

```
  scope '/company' do
    resources :company_details, only: [:new_listed_option,:index, :new, :create]
    match 'company_listings/listed_option_listing', 
       :to => 'company_listings#new_listed_option', :as => 'listed_option_listing', 
       :via => :get
    match 'company_listings/unlisted_option_listing', 
      :to => 'company_listings#new_unlisted_option', :as => 'unlisted_option_listing', 
      :via => :get
   resources :company_listings, only: [:new_listed_option, :new, :create, :edit,:destroy] do
      collection do
        get 'edit_multiple'
        get 'update_multiple' # put in to fix Heroku at least I thought that
        post 'update_multiple'
      end
    end
  end
```

When editing a Company the route displays as
http://quiet-fortress-3338.herokuapp.com/company/company_listings/211/edit
In this case 211 refers to he Company (as opposed to one of the comapny_listing.id).

Within the Company Listings controller how do I access the Comany.id (in this case 211 ?
I have tried variations of

```
@company = Company.find(params[:id])
```

Thanks in advance
Pierre

The Companies model

```
params.require(:company).
  permit(:full_name)
```

The Company_Listings model

```
params.require(:company_listing).
  permit(:company_id,
        :share_price_dollars,
        :option_unlisted,
        :exchange_id,
        :option_name,
        :option_expiration_date,
        :option_strike_price_dollars,
        :share_number,
        :company_code )
```

Therefore when adding a new option, which is one possible Company_Listing I want the Company.Id so the option has this link to the Companies table.

Comment: ActiveRecord **really** wants to control the id column. Don't have your program set the id column. Add another column if you need to store a specific value for a company, and let Rails do its own thing with the id column.

Comment: I just want the company.id as this is part of the Company_Listings model.  Thanks Pierre

Comment: Fred - thanks.  I ran without setting the company.id and it worked.  Now I only need the cache for the screen display